# How do I add SMTP to this PHP form?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, password-recovery

I **have PHPmailer** library. This is a code which is a password reminder, when you add your email to input, it will send your forgotten password to your email. This code only sends through php mail, but since my host does not allow it, only option would be to use SMTP, right? So this is the php code with form:

```
   <div class="tab-pane fade <?php
if ($tab == 'ForgotPass') {
    echo 'active in';
}
?>" id="forgotpass">
                            <form role="form2" action="index?tab=ForgotPass" method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
<?php
@$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
?>
                                    <hr class="colorgraph">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="64" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="El. paštas" value="<?= $_SESSION['email'] ?>" required>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                                            <input type="submit" name="forgot" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="send">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
<?php


if (isset($_POST['forgot'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];   

    if (empty($email)) {
        echo errorbox("Please enter email.");

    } else {
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $row2  = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
        if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0) {
            $query   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
            $row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $subject = 'Forgot Password - ' . $row['title'] . '';
            $message = '
                    <center>
                    <a href="' . $row['url'] . '" title="Visit ' . $row['url'] . '" target="_blank">
                    <h1><img src="' . $row['url'] . '' . $row['logo'] . '" title="' . $row['title'] . '"> ' . $row['title'] . '</h1>
                    </a><br />

                    <b>Registration details:</b><br />
                    Username: ' . $row2['username'] . '<b></b><br />
                    Password: ' . $row2['password'] . '<b></b><br />
                    </center>
                    ';
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'To: ' . $email . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: ' . $row['email'] . ' <' . $row['email'] . '>' . "\r\n";
            @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo okbox("We have just sent you your forgotten data from your account on the entered E-Mail Address");
        } else {
            echo errorbox("There is no player with such email.");

      }
    }
}
?>
```

---

AND i also have this **SMTP** configured code which just sends a message to test email and I already tested, it works, it does send the message, now I have to somehow make it so that it would send the password to user email:

```
<?php

require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.website.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "support@website.com";
$mail->Password = "emailpass";

$mail->From = "support@website.com";
$mail->FromName = "Test User";
$mail->AddAddress("emailthatgetsmessage@gmail.com");
//$mail->AddReplyTo("mail@mail.com");

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Test message from server via SMTP Authentication";
$mail->Body = "Test Mail sent via SMTP Authentication";
//$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";

?>
```

Comment: Just use the values from $_POST in the calls to PHPMailer.

Comment: Which file do i call? class.phpmailer or class.smtp? Could you please put an example line from $_POST? I am not good with programming...

Comment: Read the documentation, follow the examples. You've already got examples of how to get values in your first code sample.